# Docker issues when running docker build -t

Tags: java, docker

I am having issues when doing a docker build -t which states the following error in the terminal:

=> ERROR [4/4] RUN ["javac", "Main.java"]                                                                                               0.6s

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:14
COPY . /src/java
WORKDIR /src/java
RUN ["javac", "Main.java"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "main"]
```

Comment: What's the actual error?  Is there a `Main.java` file in the same directory as the Dockerfile?  What's the build command you're running?

Comment: Hi am running this "docker build -t my-java-app ." The Dockerfile is within my java folder which also contains main.java. The error is => ERROR [4/4] RUN ["javac", "Main.java"]                                                                                               0.6s

Answer (score 0):

Just going to take this from the documentation at docker hub. Open JDK does include a simple case like this it looks like this (I have made this fit your case).

```
FROM openjdk:14
COPY . /src/myapp
WORKDIR /src/myapp
RUN javac Main.java
CMD ["java", "Main"]
```

your Main.java should be in the same directory as your Dockerfile and mine looks like this (its not fancy):

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

The directory you are running from should now look like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── Main.java
```

you can run and build using this

```
$ docker build -t my-java-app .
$ docker run -it --rm --name my-running-app my-java-app
```

Check your run syntax and make your files like this, hope that helps.

Comment: still getting this issue when doing $ docker build -t my-java-app .

The error is  => ERROR [4/4] RUN ["javac", "Main.java"]                                                                                               0.6s

Comment: Just check your files against the updated above this works no worries